# Apache redirect to another port

Tags: apache, redirect

I've struggled with this for some time and am definitely doing something wrong.

I have Apache server and a JBoss server on the same machine. I'd like to redirect traffic for `mydomain.example` to JBoss `localhost:8080/example`. The DNS is currently setup for `mydomain.example` and it will go straight to port 80 when entered into the browser.

My question is how do I redirect to a different port when a certain domain name comes to Apache (in this case, `mydomain.example`)?

```
<VirtualHost ip.addr.is.here>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName mydomain.example
  ProxyPass http://mydomain.example http://localhost:8080/example
  ProxyPassReverse http://mydomain.example http://localhost:8080/example
</VirtualHost>
```

#### After implementing some suggestions:

- Still not forwarding to port 8080

  ```bash
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName mydomain.example
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.example
    ProxyPass http://mydomain.example http://localhost:8080/example
    ProxyPassReverse http://mydomain.example http://localhost:8080/example
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Comment: That looks pretty good. What are your symptoms?

Comment: Sympotms are that I put www.mydomain.com in the browser but and it goes to apache root dir.  Instead, I'd like for it to redirect to a jboss subdirectory localhost:8080/subdir.  I currently have it working for redirecting various domains straight to port 80, but cant quite get it to go to another port.

Comment: I have the exact same request: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Cystack - I couldnt quite get it to work.  I tried so many variations to the configuration it drove me crazy.  I gave up on it =/   If you happen to find a solution please post it here, I would like to know how to get this to work.  good luck my friend!

Comment: This worked for me: http://serverfault.com/a/195831/111707

Comment: I have found that Apache often prefers to load it's default site configuration which can take precedence over other virtual hosts.  The default file does not have a specific ServerName defined so if you have multiple virtual hosts running disable Apache's default: sudo a2dissite 000-default

Comment: Thanks for the tip @filitchp.  At some point I'm going to try this again just to get it working.  I have long since abandoned it, lol.  Again, much appreciated!

Comment: DON'T forget to add the correspondent modules to apache and restart, otherwise it won't work `sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You should leave out the domain `http://example.com` in ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse and leave it as `/`. Additionally, you need to leave the `/` at the end of `example/` to where it is redirecting. Also, I had some trouble with `http://example.com` vs. `http://www.example.com` - only the www worked until I made the ServerName www.example.com, and the ServerAlias example.com. Give the following a go.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/example/
</VirtualHost>
```

After you make these changes, add the needed modules and restart apache

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: enable apache modules before restarting apache -https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension#configuring-apache-to-proxy-connections

Comment: Would this be the same for a CentOS server? (I don't see why not, just making sure). And, what config file would this be? (somewhere in /etc/httpd/conf I'm guessing...)

Comment: It worked, but I saw that in the welcome page of my application, the css was not loaded (which earlier worked on example.com:8080/example). and also got some exceptions. any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: this caused an error "Service Unavailable" on my httpd until I did `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: Upvote for the a2enmod proxy & proxy_http disabled by default.

Comment: ensure you have a listen statement. If you, for example want to proxy any request coming on 8090 to 8080

add a `LISTEN 8090` outside the VirtualHost block.

Comment: Work perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 33):

I solved this issue with the following code:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName myhost.example
ServerAlias www.myhost.example
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also used:

```
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to do exactly this so I could access Jenkins from the root domain.

I found I had to disable the default site to get this to work. Here's exactly what I did.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/jenkins
```

And insert this into file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName mydomain.example
  ServerAlias mydomain
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Next you need to enable/disable the appropriate sites:

```
$ sudo a2ensite jenkins
$ sudo a2dissite default
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing @Louth.  I have long since given this up and no longer have the server.  Still bothers me that I never got it working, I may start up a new server just to test out again.  Thanks again, I'll be sure to update if/when I try this again.

Comment: The Jenkins wiki explains how to run Jenkins behind Apache : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

Answer (score 10):

This might be an old question, but here's what I did:

In a .conf file loaded by Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName something.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Explanation: Listen on all requests to the local machine's port 80.  If I requested "`http://something.com/somethingorother`", forward that request to "`http://localhost:8080/somethingorother`".  This should work for an external visitor because, according to the docs, it maps the remote request to the local server's space.

I'm running Apache 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2, so I'm not sure how the "-2ubuntu2.2" affects the wider applicability of this answer.

Comment: Didnt work for me

Answer (score 7):

Found this out by trial and error. If your configuration specifies a ServerName, then your VirtualHost directive will need to do the same. In the following example, awesome.example.com and amazing.example.com would both be forwarded to some local service running on port 4567.

```
ServerName example.com:80

<VirtualHost example.com:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName awesome.example.com
  ServerAlias amazing.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:4567/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4567/
</VirtualHost>
```

I know this doesn't exactly answer the question, but I'm putting it here because this is the top search result for Apache port forwarding. So I figure it'll help somebody someday.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Using `*:80` instead of `example.com:80` meant that the port would not be redirected.

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure that the proxy is enabled on the server. You can do so by using the following commands:

```
  a2enmod proxy
  a2enmod proxy_http

  service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Didnt work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to use a proxy to JBoss and `mydomain.example:8080` can be "exposed" to the world, then I would do this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.example
  Redirect 301 / http://mydomain.example:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Using a port other than 80 not only looks ugly, but can also cause problems with proxy servers or ISPs. In that case, just remove Apache and run JBoss on port 80 instead!

Comment: Running everything under JBoss is an option, I was just trying to avoid moving the apache sites to JBoss, but it shouldnt be overly time consuming.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a Reverse Proxy in your apache configuration (directly):

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

[Look here for apache documentation of how to use the mod](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things:

1. Add a `ServerAlias www.mydomain.example` to your config
2. change your proxypass to `ProxyPassMatch ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/example$1`, to possibly keep mod_dir and trailing slashes from interfering.

Comment: I added ServerAlias but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

My apache listens to 2 different ports,

```
Listen 8080
Listen 80
```

I use the 80 when i want a transparent URL and do not put the port after the URL
useful for google services that wont allow local url?

But i use the 8080 for internal developing where i use the port as a reference for a "dev environment"

Answer (score 0):

Apache supports name based and IP based virtual hosts. It looks like you are using both, which is probably not what you need.

I think you're actually trying to set up [name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), and for that you don't need to specify the IP address.

Try < VirtualHost *:80> to bind to all IP addresses, unless you really want [ip based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html). This may be the case if the server has several IP addresses, and you want to serve different sites on different addresses. The most common setup is (I would guess) name based virtual hosts.

Comment: That makes sense, name based is all I need.  I changed it but it still itsnt routing to the other port

Answer (score 0):

All are excellent insights to accessing ports via domain names on virtual servers. Do not forget, however, to enable virtual servers; this may be commented out:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<Directory "/home/dawba/www/">
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

We run WSGI with an Apache server at the domain sxxxx.com and a golang server running on port 6800. Some firewalls seem to block domain names with ports. This was our solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ServerName wsgi.sxxxx.example
 DocumentRoot "/home/dxxxx/www"
  <Directory "/home/dxxx/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
 ScriptAlias /py/ "/home/dxxxx/www/py/"
 WSGIScriptAlias /wsgiprog /home/dxxxx/www/wsgiprog/Form/Start.wsgi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ServerName sxxxx.com
 ServerAlias www.sxxxx.com
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:6800/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6800/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working in ISPConfig too. In website list get inside a domain, click to Options tab, add these lines: ;

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8181/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8181/
```

Then go to website and wolaa :) This is working HTTPS protocol too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.adminbackend.example.com
  ServerAlias adminbackend.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:6000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6000/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I redirected part of the requests to one url and rest to another url:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass /context/static/content http://localhost:80/web/
  ProxyPassReverse /context/static/content http://localhost:80/web/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```