# socket.io: How to abandon the url:port scheme?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I started playing with node.js and socket.io and can't figure out how to make it so you don't have to type in "url:port" in the browser but just the url. Instead i want to only type in the url and then everything should come up, like in my unfinished single player game here: http://space.bonsaiheld.org/ (you guess right: i want to make it multiplayer). The game must not run on port 80/443 as those ports are dedicated to the webserver.

It should be like this: http://ondras.zarovi.cz/games/just-spaceships/ and not "ip/url: port". How to do that?

app.js

```
// Socket.IO
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs');

// Start the server on port 9000
app.listen(9000);

// Send index.html to the player
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

// Connection listener
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client)
{
    console.log('New connection established.');
}); // Connection listener
```

index.html

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mehrspielerklötzchen</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="background: #000000;">
    <script>

    // Socket.IO
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: I basically want that the game runs on Port 9000, but the index.html be reachable over a normal/portless URL like sub.domain.com/game/ and not URL:Port.

EDIT 2: Reduced the question to only one as my two problems happen to be seperate ones.

EDIT 3: Solved! I figured it out myself, it's totally easy:

New extremly simplified server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(9000);

// Connection listener
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client)
{
    console.log('Connection established.');
}); // Connection listener
```

New index.html (reachable over file://folder/index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mehrspielerklötzchen</title>
<script src="http://localhost:9000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: #000000;">
<script>

// Socket.IO
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to everyone who helped. I guess it would have also worked with port redirecting. But it seems that i don't even need it. Now Apache serves the files as always but socket.io listens for port 9000 and the index.html (or whatever file i want) connects to the server! This also means that this file could now lie EVERYWHERE, even on another server or local. Perfect. :))

Comment: But now your solution *does* include an explicit port, I thought that's what you didn't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the default HTTP/HTTPS ports 80/443 (which are default ports for WS/WSS as well).

Of course you can [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8541182/1048572) them to other, "internal" ports.

Comment: And how to have more than one game then? Besides that, i'm using a shared hoster. My port is 9000. My linked "Just Spaceships!"-Game uses Port 1500 and you don't have to type in :1500 in the browser... That's what i also want.

Comment: How is the number of games related to the port? And you will need to enter 9000 if you're on that port only…

Comment: I can, of course, have more than one port. 9000 is just my first one. But why doesn't have the maker of that space game have to do that? Visit here: http://ondras.zarovi.cz/games/just-spaceships/ - there the wss://server adress is right of the field "Server URL". So the game runs on port 1500 but you don't have to type it in, so you COULD change it to connect to different servers.

Comment: Of course you can make some port redirection in your server config, but that depends on the server. Which one do you use?

Comment: You mean the software? My provider uses Apache 2.2.15 (CentOS). But it must work offline too for developing... Also using Apache. I basically don't want to type in "url:port" but just the normal url which could be "sub.domain.com:/index.html" and there the index.html itself loads the js files and socket.io to connect to port 9000.

Comment: You'll want to run all the games on the same port, and accept multiple connections there.  Your links are both to things being served on port 80, so there must be something that's routing port 80 to port 1500 if that's where the game is running.

Comment: @Aaron Dufour: Yeah, all games of that person are reachable over a normal port 80 website, but the games themselves internally run on different ports so the port doesn't have to be in the URL field. That's exactly what i want. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Bergi: I might try this, thanks. But how would i achieve it if i don't have any webserver installed? Because socket.io doesn't need one.

Comment: @Bergi: Sorry, forget my question. It makes no sense because this would imply that you MUST include the port on the URL field if no webserver is installed. So it might be the only possibility to achieve what i want by redirecting the ports. Does that mean that the game needs two connection listeners, for 80 and 9000? And does that mean that the game always serves it's own index.html? But that would mean that you couldn't include your games into a website like you can include flash games... without iframe.

Comment: I figoured out how to do it, without port redirecting. It's totally simple! :D See my updated question for details.