# Is there a way tor replace http://localhost:3453 with something more friendly?

Tags: linux

I have an Apache server already running on my Fedora, and it is serving me good.

Now, I am writing a simple HTTP server on a none-default port, let's say 3453.

I wanted to try replacing `http://localhost:3453` with something more friendly like http://mydomain.com

I tried playing with etc/hosts but then it doesn't accept port numbers!

Is there a simple way to make this happen?

Comment: Virtual hosts is the answer. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182

Comment: what are you using to write your own http server? Here's a node package for virtual hosts, maybe that gives you some inspiration how to add virtual hosts as a feature to your http server: https://github.com/lmtm/node-virtualhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a configuration like this in my httpd.conf that works as you desire:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ProxyPass / http://mydomain.com:3453/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.com:3453/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: +1, Don't forget to add an entry to your /etc/hosts file so mydomain.com redirects to localhost