# Apache Jboss 7 AS Redirect port Issue

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, jboss7.x

I am facing Issue when I call my sub.domain.com, I want to apache redirect me to the Jboss deployed app but when I call the sub.domain.com nothing appear but when I append the port 8080 (sub.domain.com:8080) all work fine.

so now how I can hide the port 8080 from the address bar?

Thanks

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName sub.domain.com
ServerAlias sub.domain.com
<Location /myapp>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
</Location>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtm
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: If you have a solution kindly share.Thanks

Comment: The solution can be found here: [Apache redirect to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Open standalone.xml of Jboss server.

Change 8080 port to 80 like below

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>
           ............
           ............
</socket-binding-group>
```

Restart server.

Comment: But Apache use this port