# Intellij Idea execute java with with sudo

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, sudo

I have a Java application that run Jetty server on port 80. Everything starts fine when I run the application from console:

```
sudo java -jar myapp.jar
```

When I'm trying to run the application from Intellij Idea I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:95)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:231)
```

Is there any way to run the java application with sudo from the IDE? As workaround I run Idea with sudo from command line, that solved my problem, but the Idea throwed some internal errors related to some misconfiguration and I'm not going to run the whole IDE as sudo.

Comment: Have u tried to start Intellij Idea with sudo?

Comment: Just run it on a port > 1024 while you're developing

Comment: @Harry.Chen I mentioned about it in the question, it's not a permanent solution and I'm not going to run Idea as root user

Comment: @acanby I won't post this question if I could, the app need to run on port 80 since 3rd party service expecting exactly this port and there is no way to change the config of the service

Comment: You could install Apache HTTP Server and use it as a proxy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port

Comment: @JaagupKümmel this might help as workaround, I'll try - thanks! But I still sure there should be some native way to run sudo from Idea.