# Can I use apache to forward wiki.company.com to wiki.company.com:8090?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, windows-server-2008, jira, confluence

We are running apache on a win 2008 server and have jira and confluence installed on their default ports. In our dns we want to have jira.company.com forward to 8443 and wiki.company.com forward to 8090. Is this easy to do using apache mod_rewrite or some other configuration? If so could someone share how? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache redirect to another port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)

Comment: Slightly different. We want to have two different domain names forwarding to different ports. We already have the default forwarding to Jira and need to add the other domain name to confluence. I'll touch base with our admin tomorrow to capture and share the forwarding mechanism we're currently using in Apache. Also just for reference I think we currently have entries in our DNS server to have both wiki.company.com and Jira.company.com map to the same server IP and the only issue is when we enter wiki.company.com it forwards us to Jira instead of confluence. Thank you for the reference.