# Meteor app deployment on LAMP server

Tags: node.js, apache, mongodb, meteor, lamp

I'm struggling with meteor app deployment:

I have VDS with 10 websites running on RedHat OS + Apache, MySQL, PHP.

I want install Meteor app there on specific port. It is possible?

Already installed NodeJS, MongoDB... But cant deploy simple "todo" Meteor app for example. After installing Meteor faced problem with comand: 
meteor: command not found

I know about MUP and other staff, but how I can do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `meteor up` - https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up.

I haven't done this on apache, I use nginx instead. However, what you're basically doing is a port forward / proxy. The idea is that you will get your site up and running at `00.00.00.00:3000` or `domain.com:3000`

From there you will create a virtual host that grabs all traffic going to that port and removes the port for viewing. For an example of that [please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port).

Again, I typically use nginx for this because it's easier and because nginx does a much better job of serving static assets which your meteor app will need. I've written up a blog post on how to do this step by step. [Check that out here.](http://johngibby.com/blog/How_to_deploy_your_meteor.js_app_on_Digital_Ocean). You can really use this blog post to do your entire set up, just replace the nginx part with apache.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! Will try you way