# Different port make the DNS useless

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I use XAMPP to make a website but I have the other Website use IIS so I couldn't use port 80. So I use port 8888 at XAMPP Apache for Windows OS.

If I type HTTP:/URL (my IP):8888 I could link the website, but when I use the DNS name such as shop.example.com.tw(just example).then It's not work.

I know it need to set virtual host and name base
but the default document is use port 80

How could I make the shop.example.com.tw work by port 8888 and the client-end
don't need type shop.example.com.tw:8888

Answer (score 0):

Domain Name Services (DNS) only links a (sub-)domain name to an IP address, it does not deal with IP Ports.

So the part you have listed as "URL (my IP)" would be replaced with the domain name, e.g. "something.mydomain.com". You need to still put the port number on the end because you are directing your client browsers to a non-standard HTTP(s) port. The standard ports being, of course, 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

If you want to direct a local port to a standard one externally, you need "Port Address Translation" (PAT) which is commonly available on routers. Or you need a proxy that will do the PAT for you.

Both Apache and IIS can do such redirections.

So the transformation is done in two steps:

`http://sub.domain.com:80 --> http://1.2.3.4:80
http://1.2.3.4:80 --> http://1.2.3.4:8888`

DNS takes care of the first, PAT or Web Server configuration or proxy server takes care of the second step.

Below are some examples for Apache. Note that personally I no longer use Apache as I find NGINX more performant and better to configure.

- [Apache redirect to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)
- http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-port-forwarding/

Comment: Could you give me the apache code for example . because I could realize the concept but I could not I try it on apache is not work.

Comment: Added a couple of examples for you.