# Spring Boot Project work with Apache Http Server

Tags: apache, spring-mvc

I have two project that write with spring boot, and have separate port number.

```
server.port: 23100
server.port: 23101
```

now, I want to deploy the two project into one server and shard the same port 80,
How should I do to support this case ?

I know it can use Apache Http Server to support PHP etc. how to do this will Spring Boot ?

## Update

thanks @HeadBangingSloth give this solution, general idea is to redirect 80 port  to local port number according to domain name.

- create **vhost.conf** file in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/** folder
- add following content according to your real case.
- restart http server via **service httpd restart**

  `<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.app1.com
  ServerAlias app1.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:23100/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:23100/
  </VirtualHost> 
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.app2.com
  ServerAlias app2.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:23101/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:23101/
  </VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at this question here [Apache redirect to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)

If you deploy your applications to your sever, you can set up your VirtualHosts in Apache to pass the incoming connections along

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.app1.com
  ServerAlias app1.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:23100/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:23100/
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.app2.com
  ServerAlias app2.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:23101/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:23101/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I will try it and give the feedback. it seems the correct way to do this. thanks