# Redirect domain name to my application running on port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I was wondering how can I redirect a domain name to one of my EC2 instances in AWS.

The domain name is registered in Route 53 and I have already associated it with the instance.

If I access the domain in the URL it shows the default apache2 page.

I want to redirect the domain name `www.xyv.com` to my application at the URL `http://ec2-52-63-222-150.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your server configuration?  What web server are you using?  Do you have nginx/Apache in front of it?  Ultimately you'll need to configure your web server to know about your domain name.

Comment: yes. I am using AWS server instance and apache2 is installed. I looking for a tutorial to show me how to remove the port number from the URL and associate the my domain name to EC2 instance.

Comment: Try looking for things like [Apache redirect to another port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port) (but that one is sending 80 to 8080).

Answer (score 4):

DNS can only redirect the domain name of your URL. Basically, it converts a Domain Name into an IP address.

By default, web traffic is accessed on port 80. However, your application is running on port 8080. Therefore, you can access it via `www.xyv.com:8080`.

If you do not want to specify a port, you have two choices:

- Change your application to run on the default port 80, or
- Configure your web server to send traffic that comes in on port 80 to the application on port 8080

Both of these options require changes to your web server configuration.

Comment: I see. Is there any tutorial on how to do that ? I have an application running on port 8080 "http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/8080". Instead of accessing the application on this URL I would like to access through my domain www.mysite.com, without typing the port number and ec2 URL.

Comment: So what I am trying to accomplish is that when the user type in the address www.mysite.com it will be redirect http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you may also configure your IPTABLES to redirect all traffic coming at port 80 to port 8080. (NAT table) - be noted that this redirects all traffic or from a specific source. for example, if your instance is in a private subnet, you have no public IP, and only the IP address of your jump server. You need to redirect all traffic at jump server to your instance in the private subnet. But, again, this all depends on your situation. that was only an option.