# Apache set server name to default localhost without including port :8080

Tags: php, windows, apache, http, xampp

I changed my port to 8080 so whenever user visit to website they need to include port is it possible to set to default same like using port 80. Instead of localhost:8080 should be localhost only. I need to change because my apache randomly crashing

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers will request through port 80. If you want to change that, it would have to be client wise. So, no, you can't set a default port.

The most you can do is set up the configuration to redirect traffic to the desired port. Check out on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182).