# Alias in virtual host using xamp in Laravel 5.6 project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, virtualhost

I created a virtual host in xampp for my Laravel 5.6 project.

I did this way:

- I added `127.0.0.1       project.com` in the `hosts` file in
  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
- I changed the port `80` to `8003` in the `httpd.conf` file in `C:\xampp\apache\conf` (I changed everything from `80` to `8003` in this file)
- I added this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8003>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
    ServerName project.com
</VirtualHost>
```

in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

I would like to use an alias because I do not want to use the url with the number port at the of the url. I just can access with this url: http://project.com:8003. 
I want to enter to my project with the url like this: http://project.com

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. But using a `.com` on a local host is probably not a good idea. Your issue could be caused by internal browser security. I'm not sure how this security measure works exactly, but it is meant to avoid skimming websites triggered by malware or spyware. Use `.test`, `.app` or any non-existing TLDs.

Comment: I tried with project.dev but I still need to add the port at the end of the url:  http://project.dev:8003

Comment: You may have a look at this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the port, you'll have to use port 80, as it's the standard for the `http://` scheme. The browser doesn't magically know on what port a given service is running nor it scans all of them.

Also, the `.dev` tld is also a real domain and will [most likely](https://webdevstudios.com/2017/12/12/google-chrome-63/) cause [problems](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).