# How to connect existing domain to various ports on AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, endpoint, velo

I need some help to connect these dots, if possible:

I have an EC2 server on AWS (let's call it http://ec2-foo.compute.amazonaws.com/), with different servers on each port. So:

- Alpha Server: http://ec2-foo.compute.amazonaws.com:5000
- Bravo Server: http://ec2-foo.compute.amazonaws.com:5001
- Charlie Server: http://ec2-foo.compute.amazonaws.com:5002

Also, I already have a domain outside Amazon (http://bar.com), which links to a Wix.com website. I would like to do the following:

- Alpha Server must be accessed from http://bar.com/alpha
- Bravo Server must be accessed from http://bar.com/bravo
- Charlie Server must be accessed from http://bar.com/charlie

I'm new at working with DNS and I would like some help to solve this specific problem. Is there a way to solve this? Would I need to create a main server to handle this? Which steps from AWS documentation should I follow in order to accomplish all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you need a webserver such as Apache to proxy incoming requests to different ports. DNS alone is not sufficient because DNS doesn't specify destination ports. Take a look at this answer for an example: [Apache redirect to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)