# How to route domain to port 8080 for vs code-server in apache

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have vs running fine on mydomain.com:8080 but i want to redirect it to port 80 so i can add ssl.
I have tried pretty much everything from this [git](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/issues/282) and SO[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port) but i either get a blank page or my other site thats on the server.
Yes I have reloaded cache on browser

Here are some of the errors I've seen:
(in terminal)

```
$ code-server --proxy-domain code-server.yehudaclinton.cf
info  Using config file ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
info  Using user-data-dir ~/.local/share/code-server
info  code-server 3.4.1 48f7c2724827e526eeaa6c2c151c520f48a61259
info  HTTP server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
info      - Using password from ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
info      - To disable use `--auth none`
info    - Not serving HTTPS
info    - Proxying the following domain:
info      - *.code-server.yehudaclinton.cf
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
error VS Code exited unexpectedly with code 1
```

(in browser)
WebSocket connection to 'ws://code-server.mywebsite.cf/?type=Management&reconnectionToken=7c741f1e-7934-4d76-a6e5-65a79d88a8bb&reconnection=false&skipWebSocketFrames=false' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. It has happened to me before. Browser cache!!
No matter how many times I try deleting the cache on my browser it still sees the old state of the website.

I tried it using TOR and it is working.