# Apache make subdomain and change main domain port

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, ubuntu, nuxt.js

I have vps server in Ubuntu 18.04. my backend project is Laravel so frontend is Nuxt. I want deploy my laravel project as subdomain in 80 port. example : api.domain.com. Frontend project deploy in 3000 port as main domain. example domain.com. How I configure my apache for subdomain and how redirect main domain 3000 port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your Apache to proxy port 80 -> 3000.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName api.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/your/laravel/application/path/public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you're done with configuring Apache, you'll have to enable the required Apache modules and restart.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```

*[Derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089668/3209381).]*

As for your Laravel application, I'm going to assume you've installed PHP and loaded the Apache PHP module.