# laravel websocket won't connect on production

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I created a laravel website on my localhost with the Beyondcode websockets. Everything worked fine untill I tried to upload my website to a live server. I have been searching the internet for solutions but couldn't find anything that works for me. The problem is that when the websocket tries to connect, it returns nothing. I think it has something to do with my NGINX config.

On my localhost the websocket works fine connecting over ws://127.0.0.1/... but on production neither ws:// nor wss:// works.

I got supervisor running the command `php artisan websockets:serve` on a subdomain. It just doesn't connect.

**My code:**
config/broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'host' => 'socket.website.com',
        'port' => "",
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ],
],
```

recources/js/bootstrap.js

```
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: 'key12',
wsHost: 'socket.website.com',
wssHost: 'socket.website.com',
wsPort: "",
wssPort:"",
forceTLS: true,
disableStats: true,
forceTLS: true,
enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
```

vHost Conf

```
    server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   socket.website.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    # Allow the use of websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

docRoot                   $VH_ROOT
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               info@proxeuse.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                ERROR
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10
  compressArchive         1
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:socke9530 php
}

phpIniOverride  {

}

rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.website.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.website.com/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  sslProtocol             24
  ciphers                 EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
  enableECDHE             1
  renegProtection         1
  sslSessionCache         1
  enableSpdy              15
  enableStapling           1
  ocspRespMaxAge           86400
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: for production best solution is create new subdomain like `socket.example.com` and use port 433 instead of `6001` it is easy

Comment: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#usage-with-a-reverse-proxy-like-nginx

Comment: `socket.elitewagers.proxweb.eu` it has `ssl` ? or not

Comment: `Supervisor` will run `php artisan websocket:serve` so it will run websocket on port `6001` then via nginx reverse proxiy to that subdomain  then in websocket you don't need to put `wsPort: 6001,`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Does this help? Worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964481/2562428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Laravel websocket in production via `subdomain` with `nginx`

### Step 1.

- create websocket conf file to run in background code will be like
- in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` (Debian/Ubuntu) or `/etc/supervisord.d` (Red Hat/CentOS)
  create a file `websockets.conf`
- then put this code

```sh
[program:websockets]
command=/usr/bin/php <laravel-path>/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=<username>
```

- then run `supervisorctl update` and `supervisorctl start websockets`

> In the step your laravel websocket will start in backgroud at port `6001`

### Step 2.

- create a subdomain like `socket.example.com`
- now connect to this domain to port `6001` via `nginx` code of `nginx` config is below

```sh
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   socket.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    # Allow the use of websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

> In this setup your subdomain is ready to accept websocket request but without ssl

### Step 3.

- install [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx) to get free ssl for this domain
- once install `certbot` just run `sudo certbot` then you will prompt to select a domain to get ssl

> In this step your geting ssl for you subdomain now you are ready to accept `wss` connection on this port

### Step 4.

- as your `wss` is ready on your subdomain `wss://socket.exmaple.com` you need to change some config in your `laravel-echo`(client) and `laravel-websocket`(server)
- in `bootstrap.js`

```js
wsHost: <subdomainname>,
wssHost: <subdomainname>,
wsPort: "",
wssPort:"",
forceTLS: true,
```

- in `config/broadcasting.php`

```php
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'host' => <subdomain>,// replace this with your subdomain 
        'port' => "",
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ],
],
```

> In this setup we are connection websocket to subdomain and here  port is empty because, subdomain is proxy of port `6001`

> You can verify your `wss` is working in https://www.websocket.org/echo.html in here just copy `<subdomain>/app/broadcasting?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false`

ref links

https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/starting
https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#usage-with-a-reverse-proxy-like-nginx

Comment: `enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']` uncomment this line and make sure `socket.elitewagers.proxweb.eu` in this domain you have ssl installed

Comment: `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` this error i m getting on this `wss` you can verify this in https://www.websocket.org/echo.html  with this url `wss://socket.elitewagers.proxweb.eu/app/broadcasting?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false`

Comment: make sure run websocket on port 6001 then via nginx or apache2 proxy that to `socket.elitewagers.proxweb.eu` then it will work

Comment: @Kamelsh Paul I see this answer is for the nginx It will more helpful if there is also provide how to configure Laravel Websockets in centos vps in Apache 2 server.

Comment: @JoneySpark you can check how to do proxy in apache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port

Comment: What if i have an nginx proxy server in the middle?

Comment: @Ali both can work